# Get all actors who have played in every film categor at least twice (Sakila DB)

Tags: sql

I'm running queries on Sakila DB, and I would like to get all actors who have played in every film category at least twice.

I'm having trouble to implement the condition of at least twice in the query, so I would appreciate any help with that.

My try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT first_name, last_name
FROM actor, film_category, film_actor
WHERE actor.actor_id=film_actor.actor_id AND 
film_actor.film_id=film_category.film_id 
   AND EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
              FROM film_category
              WHERE film_actor.film_id=film_category.film_id 
              )
HAVING COUNT(film_category.film_id)>1
ORDER BY first_name, last_name
```

Comment: Please don't use implicit joins. While they are still supported in most modern databases, they have been pushed out of ANSI-SQL by explicit joins well over 25 years.

Comment: Which column in the film_category table actually represents the "category" (action, drama, comedy, etc).  You are joining to see the person was in a film, but not specifying which CATEGORY.  And is there another lookup table of just the film categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

This is a complicated query.  It starts by counting the number of films for each actor/category . . . and then being sure that there are at least two and that all categories are covered.

The first part is:

```
select fa.actor_id, fc.category_id, count(*) as num_films
from film_actor fa join
     film_category fc
     on fa.film_id = fc.film_id
group by fa.actor_id, fc.category_id;
```

Next, we'll add the conditions for "at least two films" and "all categories" by using aggregation on this query and a `having` clause:

```
select actor_id
from (select fa.actor_id, fc.category_id, count(*) as num_films
      from film_actor fa join
           film_category fc
           on fa.film_id = fc.film_id
      group by fa.actor_id, fc.category_id
     ) ac
group by actor_id 
having min(num_films) >= 2 and
       count(*) = (select count(*) from category)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'm trying to select the `first_name` and the `last_name` but I'm having trouble including it in the query. I tried using this query as a sub-query, but it doesn't work when I get many results. Can you please suggest?

Comment: @Itay4 . . . Just `join` in the actors tables and include the names in the `group by`s.

Answer (score 0):

use explicit join and use having inside subquery

```
SELECT DISTINCT first_name, last_name
FROM actor a join film_actor fa
on a.actor_id=fa.actor_id
join film_category fc on  fa.film_id=fc.film_id     
WHERE      
   EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
              FROM film_category t1 join film_actor fa1
              on fa1.film_id=t1.film_id                      
              WHERE fa.actor_id=fa1.actor_id
              group by fa1.actor_id,t1.category_id
              HAVING COUNT( distinct film_category.film_id)>1
              )

ORDER BY first_name, last_name
```

Comment: Please don't use implicit joins. While they are still supported in most modern databases, they have been pushed out of ANSI-SQL by explicit joins well over 25 years.

Comment: @ZoharPeled i just eidted